# Trying to upload image mongodb(mlab)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs, multer

I am trying to upload image to server as well as to local folder using node js. But the problem is that when i try to post form with `enctype` then image saves only in local folder, and not in mongodb. But if I remove `enctype` then image saves only in mongodb.

```html
<form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/posts" >
```

My server.js file ---

```js
//call module
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path')
var multer = require('multer')
//var upload = multer({dest: './uploads'})
var routes = require('./routes/index')
const bodyParser= require('body-parser')
//var port = process.env.PORT|| 3000;

// Multer path define
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
 destination: './uploads',
 filename: function(req,file,cb){
  cb(null,file.fieldname + '_' + Date.now() +path.extname(file.originalname) );
 }
});
// init upload

var upload = multer({
 storage: storage
});


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.set('view engine','ejs');

//connect Mongodb
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var db
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://admin:test@ds147118.mlab.com:47118/neelcrud', (err, client) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  db = client.db('neelcrud') // whatever your database name is
  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3000')
  })
})

//routes
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
 res.render('index')
})
app.post('/posts',  upload.single('post_iamge'), (req,res)=>{
 
   db.collection('posts').save(req.body, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)

    console.log('saved to database')
 console.log(req.body)
 //console.log(req.file)
    res.render('index.ejs')
  })
   
})

app.get('/blog',(req,res)=>{
   db.collection('posts').find().toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    // renders index.ejs
    res.render('blog',{posts: result})
  })
})
```

My index.ejs file ---

```js
<html>
<head>

  <title>MY APP</title>
</head>
<body>
  May Node and Express be with you.
  <form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/posts" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="post" name="post_title">
    <!-- <input type="file" name="post_iamge"> -->
    <input type="file" name="post_iamge" accept=""/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="comment" name="post_comment">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```